# Trigger to check over dues

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I need a trigger to check over-dues.

If it is over due it should put some details from a table called loan to a table called fine with a fine amount but, the trigger I created is giving compilation errors.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Over_Due
  2  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON loan_table
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE due_date DATE;
  5  BEGIN
  6  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO due_date FROM loan_table l
  7     WHERE l.date_due = :new.date_due;
  8     IF(date_due > SYSDATE)
  9     THEN
 10  INSERT INTO fine_table VALUES(fine_id, :old.loan_id,:old.book_id,:old.student_id,amount);
 11  END IF;
END; 12
 13  /
```

---

```
 Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

 SQL> show errors;
 Errors for TRIGGER OVER_DUE:

 LINE/COL ERROR
 -------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
 3/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
 3/8      PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got
         NUMBER
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a big problem with your design: Triggers are *event* based - yours only fires when a *new* loan is made. What happens if a book is overdue and no one loans a book for a while? The answer is, nothing! The overdue detection is not made until a book is borrowed. Also, the same check is made *every time* a book is borrowed, which is too often.

Instead, what you need is a *periodic* check of *all* records - I would recommend once per day, timed to run after the library has closed (so your processing does not affect transaction performance) that checks for the existence of overdue books.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value of Count(*) (a number) into a DATE field (due_date).

I suspect what you intend to do here is:

```
select l.due_date into due_date from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be

`SELECT COUNT(*) INTO due_date`

`COUNT(*)` will never be of a `DATE` type.

You probably want to modify it like

```
...
DECLARE due_date DATE;
BEGIN
SELECT l.date_due INTO due_date FROM loan_table l
    WHERE l.date_due = :new.date_due ORDER BY l.date_due ASC LIMIT 1;
    IF(due_date > SYSDATE)
    THEN
...
```

which will check the oldest `l.date_due` against `SYSDATE` and do the insert accordingly. If you need something else, you need to be more specific.